# How to write time like this

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
timestamp = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
print timestamp
> 1542391584
```

I use python2.7 , how do I write time like this ! (13 numbers)

```
> 1542397474992
```

> (13 numbers)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I want to write time like this (1542397474992) But consists of 13 numbers

Comment: Yes, that's what you wrote in the question, but it's not stall clear to me what you actually mean by that. Are you asking how to input a timestamp in milliseconds? Or output one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.time()` returns the number of seconds (with fractions) since Epoch, so you can multiply it by 1000 to obtain the number of milliseconds since Epoch:

```
>>> from time import time
>>> int(time() * 1000)
1542403018144
```

Comment: python 2.7 : int(time.time() * 1000)

Comment: No, it does not matter if you're using Python 2.7. If you do `from time import time` then you can simply call `time()` instead of `time.time()`. Use `time.time()` only if you `import time`.